# How does this assignment work?

Tags: php

I don't know whether something similar has been asked.Can someone explain how the assignment works in the following cases:

```
$a = "1"; $a[$a] = "2"; echo $a;
```

This gives output : 12

```
$a = "1"; $a[$a] = 2; echo $a;
```

This gives output : 12

```
$a = 1; $a[$a] = 2; echo $a;
```

This gives output: E_WARNING : type 2 -- Cannot use a scalar value as an array -- at line 6
1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building a string in first and second case:

```
$a = "1"; //string with "1" character on index 0

$a[$a] = "2"; //on second index you put "2". The equivalent of the following:

$a[1]="2" 
$a{1}="2" 
$a[1]=2 
$a{1}=2;
```

As you use it as a string, `2` is cast as string, that's why case 1 and 2 give the same result.

Similarly, in first case, as you use `"1"` string as an index, it is converted to integer in `$a[$a]`.

In last case `$a` is integer, you cannot add characters onto next position as in string

Answer (score 5):

The first two examples you have provided are using strings. Strings can be treated as an array and characters accessed by their integer positions.

In the third example, you're assigning `$a` as an integer which has no character positions to reference.

Answer (score 2):

The following data structures support array dereferencing:

- [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (*)
- An object that implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.

*(*) Strings don't support the `[]` operator, though.*

The other data types (such as [integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)) don't support it, and because both strings and arrays support the `[n]` operator, it can't be coerced into another type.

In your examples:

```
$a = "1"; $a[$a] = "2";
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$a = "1"; 
$a[(int)"1"] = "2"; // or $a[1] = "2";
```